# SQL Query - select one if exists else other, never both

Tags: sql

Let's say there is a table with two columns, First Name and Eye Color.

In this table you could potentially have:

```
Name - Green Eyes
Name - Brown Eyes
```

I'm trying to select all the rows for names with green eyes, but if there is a name that doesn't have green eyes, then I would like to select the name with Brown eyes.  I never want to return two rows for a given name.  Any thoughts on how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What are your actual column names and the values they take?

Comment: Looks like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12051863/is-it-possible-to-use-if-else-in-sql might interest you?

Comment: The actual column names are EXTERNAL_ENTITY and RATING_SOURCE_NAME.  It's part of a much bigger query.  The possibilities for rating_source_name are 'S&P' and 'Moody's'.  Some entities have a rating for both S&P and Moody's, and if that is the case, I only want to see the row with S&P.  However, if the entity does not have an S&P rating, and only has Moodys, then I want to see the Moodys rating.

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT COALESCE(g.name, b.name) name,
    COALESCE(g.eye_color, b.eye_color) eye_color

FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, eye_color
  FROM eye_colors
  WHERE eye_color = 'green'
) g

FULL OUTER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT name, eye_color
  FROM eye_colors
  WHERE eye_color = 'brown'
) b
ON b.name = g.name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will let you know if it works when I figure out how to merge it with my larger query.

Answer (score 1):

```
IF EXISTS(SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Color='Green')
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Color = 'Green'
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM Table WHERE Color='Brown'
```

Answer (score 0):

I would do

```
select * 
from person 
where person.eyecolor = 'green' 
   or (     person.eyecolor = 'brown' 
        and not exists(select null from person where person.eyecolor = 'green')
      )
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, but this didn't work for my situation.

Comment: @user1623682 Can you explain how this result differs from your desired result? I'm curious because as you describe the problem, I believe this to be exactly the solution; so either I misunderstand your problem, or I'm incorrect in my logic, and in either case I want to know! :D

Comment: You are right, your soultion does work for what I described, and I tested it in a stripped down query of mine and it worked there as well. I don't know exactly why it didn't work with my larger query but I was finally able to get what I needed by adding a case statement in a where clause "and asv.rating_source_id = (case when asv.rating_source_id in (1,3) then 1 else 3 end)" Thanks so much for your help, the next time I will do a better job of describing specifics of what I need.

Answer (score 0):

I would have an index on the (name,color) for the table, then join to itself, but take the primary "Green" first, then look for brown

```
select
      justName.Name,
      coalesce( Green.Eye_Color, Brown.Eye_Color ) as Eye_Color
   from
      ( select distinct name 
           from eye_colors ) justName
         left join eye_colors as Green
            on justName.Name = Green.Name
           and Green.Eye_Color = 'Green'
         left join eye_colors as Brown
            on justName.Name = Brown.Name
           and Brown.Eye_Color = 'Brown'
```

The pre query just gets distinct names, then by left-join to the table twice, once for green, second by brown.  If the green record has no match, it gets the brown instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
select *
from person p
inner join (
    select decode(count(name), 1, 'Green Eyes', 'Brown Eyes') as color
    from person
    where color = 'Green Eyes'
    and rownum < 2
) t
on p.color = t.color
```

Subquery should return 'Green Eyes' if there is at least one person with 'Green Eyes', otherwise will return 'Brown Eyes'. Instead of inner join we could use where clause for filtering.

Comment: Can you please explain what your query does? it might be hard for someone new to understand what is happening in your query

Comment: Subquery should return 'Green Eyes'  if there is at least one person with 'Green Eyes', otherwise will return 'Brown Eyes'. Instead of inner join we could use where clause for filtering.

Comment: can you please edit your answer with this? It will be helpful for people to understand and appreciate your answer, else it might get lost in the comments.

Comment: Thank you and sorry for inconvenience.

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help too :-)